# Linting with standard.js in Intellij IDEA

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, npm, angular5

I'm trying to use standard.js for linting in Intellij. I followed the instructions for installing the node module and the Webstorm directions for manually enabling linting since the IDE did not enable it automatically. I am still getting no indication that lint is working in the editor, as I've introduced a bunch of obvious code standard flaws.

Here is the general sequence I followed:

- Installed the standard.js module. Verified that it and eslint are both included as project level node modules in package.json.
- Removed any other references to lint modules from project level package.json.
- Disabled tslint plugin.
- Removed tslint.json
- Preferences | Editor | Code style | JavaScript and click Set from Predefined Style – Standard
- Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code quality tools | ESLint

  - in EsLint package: select node_modules/standard
- Did another npm install and restarted a few times. Attempted to enable and disable EsLint a couple times just in case.

Still no lint messages appearing directly in the editor. Anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: we are not aware of such issues. Please provide your package.json, screenshot of **Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code quality tools | ESLint** and idea.log (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files). Note that **Set from Predefined Style** doesn't enable linting - it just  changes your code style preferences to the predefined "standard" scheme

Comment: BTW, what files are you trying to lint? javascript or typescript?

Comment: I think I'm just going to create a support ticket through my JetBrains account for this one since I have some company-specific information that I'd rather not post on stack. Once we figure it out I'll post the solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

standard.js only lints Javascript by default. To make it work for Typescript, you need to set it up to use `typescript-eslint-parser` as the parser and `eslint-plugin-typescript` as a plugin (https://standardjs.com/#can-i-use-a-javascript-language-variant-like-flow-or-typescript):

```
"standard"       : {
    "parser" : "typescript-eslint-parser",
    "plugins": [
      "typescript"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-typescript": "^0.9.0",
    "standard"                : "^11.0.0",
    "typescript"              : "2.6.1",
    "typescript-eslint-parser": "^9.0.0"
  }
```

[image]